# How to launch Facebook with Button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, facebook

Hey friends
I created a button on my app called: "Find us on Facebook". Right now I ran into a situation where I need the button to launch the Facebook application. I could really use some help such as launching the facebook application, detecting if there is a facebook application, and all the sorts of stuff like that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some googling shows that the facebook app apparently registers to receive urls with the `fb://` scheme.  So you can construct a `fb://` url (like, say `fb://notes` or something) and then ask the `UIApplication` object if it [can open the URL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW50).  If it says that it can, then [open it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW50).

Answer (score 1):

there is a tutorial and sample app at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Basically you need to try to call fb://profile/yourpageid to load the FB app on your page.
The sample app shows you how to do this and fall back to loading in Safari if the app is not installed on the device.

Comment: hey man, sorry to break it out to u but the sample app kinda crashed, so it does not work

Comment: It worked for me and I am now using it successfully in one of my apps. To open facebook app to a specific profile, set up the URL and call facebook connect API: 
  [_facebook handleOpenURL:url];

Comment: @MarkC can I actually detect if facebook app is installed before doing authorization?